# initializing char array in main vs in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, char

im attempting to initialize an array of chars

if I do it like this in main it works fine

```
char arr1[20] = "initial";
printf("%s", arr1);
```

but if I try to do it anywhere else such as in a struct, then try to use it in my main function like

```
struct foo 
{
    char arr1[20] = "initial";
}

int main(void)
{
     struct foo foobar;
     printf("%s", foobar.arr1);
}
```

or

```
struct foo 
{
    char arr1[20];
}

int main(void)
{
     struct foo foobar;
     foobar.arr1 = "initial";
     printf("%s", foobar.arr1);
}
```

I start getting errors. Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: this code: struct foo 
{
    char arr1[20] = "initial";
} has two problems: 1) there is a missing final ';' 2) cannot initialize a struct contents in the definition of the struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up a *struct definition* with *initialization of a variable*.

The struct definition says which types make up a struct and what their names are, e.g.:

```
struct foo 
{
    char arr1[20];
};
```

says that "`struct foo` is a type we've just defined that consists of an array[20] of `char`". There are no actual variables of this type yet.

Then you can declare and initialize instances of this type, in a similar way to how you declare and initialize `arr1` in your first example:

```
struct foo foobar = { "initial" };
```

Comment: This is what I was getting confused on. Thanks!

Comment: Why `foobar.arr1 = "initial";` will not work? As `foobar` is instance of the structure and it is assignment to a structure member

Comment: @Swanand arrays cannot be assigned to as a whole in C (they can only be initialized , or have each individual array element assigned to).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I dont suppose wrapping the whole thing in curly braces and reinitializing it would work? (even if it is bad form) like

     foobar.arr1 = { "initial" };

Comment: @AOTA That's assignment. Initialization is when you provide values at the point of declaration.

Comment: are you able to assign it like that. or can that only be used at initialization?

Comment: @AOTA arrays cannot be assigned to

Answer (score 2):

Try like this..

```
struct foo 
{
char arr1[20];
}

int main(void)
{
 struct foo foobar;
 strcpy(foobar.arr1,"initial");
 printf("%s", foobar.arr1);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to know the reason "Why does one work and the other doesn't?"

Comment: For `structure` when you are declare any variable, at the time only memory is allocated for that structure; In 2nd block of code, Before allocating memory (i.e)before declaring any variable for structure , you tried to access member of structure.